# Assume the edges of the complete bigraph $K_{100,100}$ is colored randomly.

Tags: graph-theory

Randomly coloring the edges of a given graph in red and blue.

Assume the edges of the complete bigraph $K_{100,100}$ is colored randomly. 
Show that probability that   $K_{100,100}$ is monochromatic is less than $1/10^{2500}$.

I feel like I should use the probabilistic method but I do not know how to start it.

Comment: How many colours are you allowed?

Comment: in red and blue. Sorry I forgot to add this.

Comment: You should edit the question to include this ...

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

If you colour the edges of a graph red or blue, independently, with probability $1/2$ for each edge having a given colour, then the probability they are all red is $1/2^N$ where $N$ is the number of edges. Likewise
for the probability that they are all coloured blue. So the probability the graph is monochromatic is $2/2^N$.

For $K_{r,s}$ (complete bipartite) what is $N$?

Comment: So the probability is $1/2^{9999}$? by the way how can I compare this number with $1/10^{2500}$?

Comment: @jiqiudabao logarithms?

Comment: I will try. Thank you a lot for your answer!